# While and foreach mixed loop issue

Tags: perl, foreach

## !C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my $numArgs = $#ARGV + 1;
print "thanks, you gave me $numArgs command-line arguments.\n";



while (my $line = <DATA> ) { 
    foreach my $argnum (0 .. $#ARGV) {
        if ($line =~ /$ARGV[$argnum]/)
            {
                print $line;
            }
    }
} 

__DATA__ 
A
B
Hello World :-)
Hello World !
```

when I passed one arg, it works well.
Such as I run **test.pl A** or  **test.pl B** or  **test.pl Hello"

when I passed two args, it works some time only.

Successful: When I run **test.pl A B** or  **test.pl A Hello** or  **test.pl B Hello"

Failed: when I run **test.pl Hello World***

Produced and output duplicate lines:

```
D:\learning\perl>t.pl Hello World
thanks, you gave me 2 command-line arguments.
Hello World :-)
Hello World :-)
Hello World !
Hello World !

D:\learning\perl>
```

How to fix it? Thank you for reading and replies.

[update]
I don't want to print duplicate lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the problem, your script processes the `__DATA__` and tests all input words against it: since "Hello" and "World" match twice each, it prints 4 rows.

If you don't want it to write multiple lines, just add `last;` after the `print` statement.

Comment: Hi Kemp. yes, as you said. But I don't want to print duplicate lines. thank you.

Comment: Then add a `last;` just after the `print` statement.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting the duplicate output is because the regex `$line =~ /Hello/` matches both "Hello World" lines and `$line =~ /World/` also matches both "Hello World" lines.  To prevent that, you'll need to add something to remember which lines from the `__DATA__` section have already been printed so that you can skip printing them if they match another argument.

Also, some very minor stylistic cleanup:

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe
use strict;
use warnings;

my $numArgs = @ARGV;
print "thanks, you gave me $numArgs command-line arguments.\n";

while (my $line = <DATA> ) { 
    foreach my $arg (@ARGV) {
        if ($line =~ /$arg/)
            {
                print $line;
            }
    }
} 

__DATA__ 
A
B
Hello World :-)
Hello World !
```

- Using an array in scalar context returns its size, so `$size = @arr` is preferred over `$size = $#arr + 1`
- If you're not going to use a counter for anything other than indexing through an array (`for $i (0..$#arr) { $elem = $arr[$i]; ... }`), then it's simpler and more straightforward to just loop over the array instead (`for $elem (@arr) { ... }`).

Your `foreach` loop could also be replaced with a `grep` statement, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Hi Dave, I found a bug. If i run `test.pl World Hello`,(swap *Hello World* to *World Hello*) The output still wrong. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to print each line from `DATA` only once if one or more patterns match, you can use `grep`. Note that use of `\Q` to quote regex metacharacters in the command line arguments and the use of the `@patterns` array to precompile the patterns.

Read `if grep { $line =~ $_ } @patterns` out loud: *If `$line` matches one or more patterns* ;-)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

printf "Thanks, you gave me %d command line arguments.\n", scalar @ARGV;

my @patterns = map { qr/\Q$_/ } @ARGV;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    print $line if grep { $line =~ $_ } @patterns;
}

__DATA__
A
B
Hello World :-)
Hello World !
```

Here are some comments on your script to help you learn:

```
my $numArgs = $#ARGV + 1;
print "thanks, you gave me $numArgs command-line arguments.\n";
```

The command line arguments are in [`@ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@ARGV) (please do read the documentation). In scalar context, `@ARGV` evaluates to the number of elements in that array. Therefore, you can simply use:

```
printf "Thanks, you gave me %d command line arguments.\n", scalar @ARGV;
```

Further, you can iterate directly over the elements of `@ARGV` in your `foreach` loop instead of indexed access.

```
while (my $line = <DATA> ) { 
    foreach my $arg ( @ARGV ) {
        if ( $line =~ /$arg/ ) {
            print $line;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, what happens to your program if I pass `(` to it on the command line? Or, even `World?` What should happen?

Comment: BTW, when I passed `(` to my program above, produced and generated an error `Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/( <-- HERE / at D:\learning\perl\t .pl line 13, <DATA> line 1.` , Otherwise World? works well. Your script above fixed this bug.

Comment: @Nano HE Rica ederim ;-) The main question is, do you want `World?` to match the input given that there is no string `World?` in `__DATA__`. It is matching because `d?` means the `d` is optional in the pattern. Using `\Q` in the pattern before interpolating `$_` into the `qr` means the `?` would be quoted and now `?` would have to match literally.